# Is it possible to have both Slideshow and RotatorType.SlideShowButtons?

Tags: telerik, rotator

Telerik control: Is it possible to have both rotator types?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think so, or at least have not found a way to do that. But you may try to mix SlideShow mode with custom buttons (see [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/rotator/examples/pagerintegration/defaultcs.aspx) for the latter) if appropriate.

Comment: How would I combined them? I really appreciated your help on this.

Comment: What I have in mind is to switch on SlideShow mode for the rotator and move between certain items in it with custom buttons as presented in the example (if doable).